# jQuery Validate plugin - Handling of error messages

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

Can I have some help for my form please

I use the validate plugin.

http://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/2pLS2/23/

I would like a single general message for all empty fields and once the field is filled with a custom field below the concerned message (like "Please enter at least 2 characters")

How can I do that please ?

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    errorClass: 'error-image',
    validClass: 'ok-image',
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorContainer: '#invalid-empty',
    errorPlacement: function(error,element) {
    return true;
  }
});

$("#form-general").validate({

    rules: {
        firstname: {
            minlength: 2,
            maxlength: 25
        },
        name: {
            minlength: 2,
            maxlength: 25
        },
        email: {
            email: true
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: i just came across [`invalidHandler`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/). *"Callback for custom code when an invalid form is submitted. Called with an event object as the first argument, and the validator as the second."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `messages` option to specify custom messages.

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fungku/n83mM/) for a demo.

**Adding custom `messages` to the options and remove empty `errorPlacement`:**

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
  errorClass: 'error-image',
  validClass: 'ok-image',
  errorElement: 'span',
  errorContainer: '#invalid-empty',
  //errorPlacement: function(error,element) {
  //  return true;
  //},
  messages: {
    name: {
      required: "",
      minlength: "Dude, your first name is longer than that..."
    },
    firstname: {
      required: "",
      minlength: "I know you can type at least one more character!"
    },
    email: {
      required: "",
      email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com"
    },
    telephone: "",
    message: ""
  }
});
```

Just specify whatever rule you want to over-ride the default message for, and write your custom message.

Since you only want your general `required` message at the top, you can just overwrite `required` messages as empty strings so that nothing shows up below the input.

Comment: Thank you. In fact I would like a single general message for all empty fields and once the field is filled with a custom field below the concerned message.

Comment: @Xroad I updated the javascript and JSFiddle to match your specs ;)

Comment: I had not thought to leave "required" custom messages empty. It works ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your `errorPlacement` option and it will do that automatically.  By having this:

```
errorPlacement: function(error,element) {
    return true;
}
```

You are telling jQuery Validate to not place error messages at all.  Removing it will allow the plugin to place the messages, which sounds like what you want.  If you want to skip required messages but allow the other messages, you might have to get fancy with the `error` part of errorPlacement.  It contains the message string, so it will say something about "required", which you could RegExp for and not display.

Perhaps:

```
errorPlacement: function(error,element) {
    if (/required/.test(error.text()){
        return false;
    } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. In fact I had not thought to leave "required" custom messages empty.